# Debian power button won't suspend if monitor not plugged in

Tags: linux, debian

Having changed systemd/logind.conf as follows:

```
HandlePowerKey=suspend
```

with a desktop monitor plugged in the computer suspends on pressing the power button.

As launched without desktop connected, suspension does not work. I tried setting
/`usr/sbin/pm-suspend` in powerbtn-acpi-support.sh for good measure with no change.

What is the problem? My system is Debian 8.

Comment: Same here (Debian 10). If a monitor is connected, a 60 seconds timeout appears, after that the system shuts down. If no monitor is connected, the system doesn't shutdown, even after 60+ seconds. Interestingly, when no monitor is connected, the power button is pressed and afterwards a monitor is connected, the system shuts down immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure what was causing the error, but I disabled the Gnome desktop manager ( `systemctl set-default multi-user.target` ) and the suspend function works as desired.